# iOS. Get bundle if from different target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, ios11

I have app with 2 targets: main app and safari extension.
How can I get bundle id for safari extension target in the main app class?

I need it programmatically. Not a constant. 
This code does not work:

```
         let bundleId = Bundle(for: NSClassFromString("ContentBlockerRequestHandler")!.self).bundleIdentifier!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a constant at your safari extension target: general panel.

So your main app should have a similar string. like "WhateverHere". Then you can get : id = "WhateverHere" + ".safari".

As to your main app, you can get bundleID : Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier,

then the rest depends on how you name it.

[image]